# Не создаются столбцы в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Создаю список, делаю его источником для грида

```
List<DisplayLesson> SRC = new List<DisplayLesson>
{
     new DisplayLesson("8:00", "Ксенология"),
     new DisplayLesson("8:55", "Ксенология"),
     new DisplayLesson("10:00", "Ксенология")
};

MondayGrid.ItemsSource = SRC;
MondayGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

На выходе DataGrid без колонок, но с элементами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

AutoGenerateColumns включён

Answer (score 0):

В описании класса у переменных не было { get; set; }

Было

```
   public class DisplayLesson
{
    public string Time;
    public string Subject;

    public DisplayLesson(string T, string S)
    {
        Time = T;
        Subject = S;
    }
}
```

Стало

```
   public class DisplayLesson
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public DisplayLesson(string T, string S)
    {
        Time = T;
        Subject = S;
    }
}
```